# Why do I have duplicate packages installed by Homebrew

Tags: homebrew

A recent update (of `cloog`, I think) resulted in what look like duplicate entries listed by `brew list`:

```
...
gmp
gmp@4
...
isl
isl@0.12
...
```

What are these and why are they present? Can I get rid of them? Are they likely to cause any issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@` prefixed formula is old version formula, or "versioned formula".

For example, `llvm` on homebrew is 3.9.1, but `llvm@3.7` is 3.7.1.

The package like this exists for one who wants to use the old version, or as a dependency for the another 
 versioned formula.

AFAIK versioned formula won't cause a problem.

You can get rid of one unless it is a dependency of something.

Comment: And I assume that I can safely learn something by simply doing `brew uninstall SOMETHING` followed by `brew upgrade` to get back any needed dependencies that that shouldn't have uninstalled.